# Changing theme in manifest Appcompat v7 (API 21) (you need to use an Theme.Appcompat theme)

Tags: android, themes, manifest, android-appcompat

While trying to update my app to a material design look, I added Appcompat v7 library to my project(last update), Everything works well for now but I'm forced to declare a theme in the manifest (wich I wasn't before working with Appcompat Lib).

> Theme.AppCompat.Light

And when I change the theme in my app with

> setTheme(pink);

the status bar color choosen with

> name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/pink

stays the same color as in the theme declared in the manifest.

So here is my question how can I change the status bar color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(color)`.

Comment: I have the same problem with changing from dark to light theme. The  WindowBackground stays the same color. If it's "Theme.AppCompat" in the manifest it stays dark while changing to Light theme in the app.

Answer (score 1):

I found the proper solution to all this, the

```
 setTheme(theme);
```

method should be called before

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```